# Object creation/deletion/updates restrictions for all user/admins but a specific one: AWS S3 Bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that gets triggered when a create object action occurred in a specific S3 bucket. I need to make the following restrictions in my bucket for all users/roles (including admins), but a specific user. They are:

- Deny Object creation (meaning manually uploading a new file anywhere in the bucket or in its sub-folders)
- Deny Object deletion (meaning manually deleting an existing file anywhere in the bucket or in its sub-folders)
- Deny Object overwriting or copy (meaning manually overwrite a file with the same name or making a copy of it anywhere in the bucket and in its sub-folders - please note that Versioning is OFF)
- Deny Object renaming (meaning manually rename an existing file in the bucket or in its sub-folders)

I also need to preserve all lambda's write access to my bucket as specified in my inline policy. In order to achieve all the above, I have put together the following Bucket Policy:

```
{
            "Id": "my-bucket-policy",
            "Statement": [
                    {
                            "Action": [
                                  "s3:DeleteObject",
                                  "s3:PutObject"
                                      ],
                            "Effect": "Deny",
                            "NotPrincipal": {
                                    "AWS": [
                                            "arn:aws:iam::1234555:user/allowedUser"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "Resource": [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket/",
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket/*"
                            ]
                    }
            ],
            "Version": "2012-10-17"
    }
```

This does not work and I am returned with an 'Invalid principal in policy' message. Can you see anything clearly wrong with my policy? Is this the correct way to go to meet my requirements?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out your policy in my environment and it works for me.

Your logic is correct, however your Lambda functions will not be able to write to the bucket even if you allow s3:putObject action in Lambda execution policy. The bucket policy explicitly denies all writes to the bucket except the allowed user and an explicit deny always wins in AWS policies.

The solution is to include the Lambda execution role inside NotPrincipal.

Just to note that, both putObject and deleteObject are object-level actions, so you don't need to specify top-level bucket ARN (arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket/) as a resource in the bucket policy.